# Docker: the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system

Tags: docker, bcmath

I am getting below error while installing bcmath

```
root@cfe90ea33de0:/var/www/web# apt install php-bcmath
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php-bcmath is a virtual package provided by:
  php7.3-bcmath 7.3.14-1~deb10u1 [Not candidate version]
  php7.3-bcmath 7.3.11-1~deb10u1 [Not candidate version]
  php7.0-bcmath 7.0.33-0+deb9u7 [Not candidate version]
  php7.0-bcmath 7.0.33-0+deb9u6 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'php-bcmath' has no installation candidate
```

I tried with below command still same error

```
apt-get install php7.3-bcmath
apt-get install php7.0-bcmath
V=`php -v | sed -e '/^PHP/!d' -e 's/.* \([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\).*$/\1/'` \apt-get install php$V-bcmath
```

Answer (score 30):

```
docker-php-ext-install bcmath
```

Above command works, after logged in to the Docker.

Answer (score 7):

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
```

Add this in your Docker file and rebuild docker image.